# Пустая строка из-за include PHP

Tags: include, php

```
﻿<?php
session_start();
$el = $_GET['el'];
include('newsread.php');
echo '
<html>
    <head>.......
```

Если инклуд в таком положении(перед html), появляется лишняя строка. Если он после хеад в разрыва echo, то теряется то что перед ним(html и head). В инклуде ничего не выводится. В чем проблема?

Comment: А на русском?

Comment: лишняя строка у вас появляется от того что перед `'<html>'` в echo выводится символ новой строки. а вот почему теряется после `'<head>'` это надо посмотреть как вы вставляете `include` в 'разрыв'

Comment: а зачем делать "`echo '<html>';`" ? почему не сделать это вне php? или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за помощь. Проблема в include, в нем осталось echo...

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
session_start();
$el = $_GET['el'];
include('newsread.php');
?><html>
    <head>.......
```

или

```
﻿<?php
session_start();
$el = $_GET['el'];
include('newsread.php');
echo '<html>
    <head>.......
```

И перед <html> пустой строки не будет.